# PHP Save array in database and miss data

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I need to save in database category like "a & b" but the model save in database just "a" miss the blank space and the &.

This is the array:

```
$data = array('avenvu'        => $_POST['avenvu'],
              'brand'         => $_POST['brand'],
              'category'      => $_POST['category'],
              'description'   => $_POST['description'],
              'man_women_shop'=> $_POST['man_women_shop'],
              'postdatetime'  => date("Y-m-d H:i:s",time()), 
              'publish'       => 1,  
              'user_id'       => $this->session->userdata('user_id'));

$result = $this->personal_closest->insertCloset($data);
```

And this is the model:

```
function insertCloset($data) {
    $this->db->insert('personal_closest',$data);
}
```

Comment: remove htmlspecialchars and try. and try to change column collasion to utf-8-bin. at the time of shoeing category htmlspecialchars will be needed.

Comment: same error i've try.

Comment: ok write mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['category']);

Comment: mysqli_real_escape_string() need 2 parameters

Answer (score 3):

Change your `insertCloset` function:

```
function insertCloset($data) {

    $personal['avenvu']         =  $data['avenvu'];
    $personal['brand']          =  $data['brand'];
    $personal['category']       =  $data['category'];
    $personal['description']    =  $data['description'];
    $personal['man_women_shop'] =  $data['man_women_shop'];
    $personal['postdatetime']   =  $data['postdatetime'];
    $personal['publish']        =  $data['publish'];
    $personal['user_id']        =  $data['user_id'];

    $this->db->insert('personal_closest',$personal);
}
```